# SDWebImage not download image after change from http to https

Tags: objective-c, sdwebimage

I have in My project a table with images.

the image url start with http:

in tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath I download image foreach cell with this method.

```
- (void)sd_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder options:(SDWebImageOptions)options progress:(SDWebImageDownloaderProgressBlock)progressBlock completed:(SDWebImageCompletionBlock)completedBlock {
[self sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad];
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &imageURLKey, url, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);

if (!(options & SDWebImageDelayPlaceholder)) {
    dispatch_main_async_safe(^{
        self.image = placeholder;
    });
}

if (url) {

    // check if activityView is enabled or not
    if ([self showActivityIndicatorView]) {
        [self addActivityIndicator];
    }

    __weak __typeof(self)wself = self;
    id <SDWebImageOperation> operation = [SDWebImageManager.sharedManager downloadImageWithURL:url options:options progress:progressBlock completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
        [wself removeActivityIndicator];
        if (!wself) return;
        dispatch_main_sync_safe(^{
            if (!wself) return;
            if (image && (options & SDWebImageAvoidAutoSetImage) && completedBlock)
            {
                completedBlock(image, error, cacheType, url);
                return;
            }
            else if (image) {
                wself.image = image;
                [wself setNeedsLayout];
            } else {
                if ((options & SDWebImageDelayPlaceholder)) {
                    wself.image = placeholder;
                    [wself setNeedsLayout];
                }
            }
            if (completedBlock && finished) {
                completedBlock(image, error, cacheType, url);
            }
        });
    }];
    [self sd_setImageLoadOperation:operation forKey:@"UIImageViewImageLoad"];
} else {
    dispatch_main_async_safe(^{
        [self removeActivityIndicator];
        if (completedBlock) {
            NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:SDWebImageErrorDomain code:-1 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : @"Trying to load a nil url"}];
            completedBlock(nil, error, SDImageCacheTypeNone, url);
        }
    });
}
  }
```

in plist I have this
     NSAllowsArbitraryLoads

the problem start when I remove the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads from Plist file
and change the url to https: a couple images download grate and a few don't download.

what can be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my app (an old one) I have some images to download.
when I tried to do this with SDWebImage, there is no results.

My solution is to copy my Image url to safari, and get the direct URL and use it.

the problem I think is with redirect url, when there is redirect url, SDWebImage cannot download this image.

Try it and let me know if I have the correct answer to myself :)